# ValueError: shapes (4,87) and (4,87) not aligned: 87 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, logistic-regression

I am trying to implement the logistic regression from scratch with the data shape : `x_train[0], len(x_train)` be `([0.0, 0.0, 0.93, 0.07], 87)` but I am receiving an error. I am sure the error is causing due to mismatch of shape of w but I am unable to resolve it.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [41], line 23
     21 iterations = 1000
     22 learning_rate = 1e-3
---> 23 w, b, loss = logistic_regression(np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train), learning_rate, iterations)

Cell In [41], line 12, in logistic_regression(x_train, y_train, learning_rate, iterations)
     10 A = 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
     11 cost = (-1/m)*np.sum(y_train*np.log(A)+(1-y_train)*np.log(1-A))
---> 12 dw = (1/m)*np.dot((A-y_train),x_train.T)
     13 db = (1/m)*np.sum(A-y_train)
     14 weights = weights - learning_rate*dw.T

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (4,87) and (4,87) not aligned: 87 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)
```

```
def logistic_regression(x_train, y_train, learning_rate, iterations):
    m = len(x_train)
    n = len(x_train[0])
    weights = np.zeros((m,1))
    b = 0
    for i in range(iterations):
        loss = []
        z = np.dot(x_train.T,weights) + b
        A = 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
        cost = (-1/m)*np.sum(y_train*np.log(A)+(1-y_train)*np.log(1-A))
        dw = (1/m)*np.dot((A-y_train),x_train.T)
        db = (1/m)*np.sum(A-y_train)
        weights = weights - learning_rate*dw.T
        b = b - learning_rate*db
        loss.append(cost)
        if (i%(iterations/10) == 0):
            print("Cost after iteration %i: %f" %(i, cost))
    return weights,b, loss

iterations = 1000
learning_rate = 1e-3
w, b, loss = logisitic_regression(np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train), learning_rate, iterations)
```

Comment: `np.dot` has well documented rules about how the dimensions of the arrays match.  You got that wrong in `np.dot((A-y_train),x_train.T)`.  I won't try to sort out the dimensions for you.  But evidently you got them right earlier in the `z` line.

Answer (score 1):

You really should tell us the dimensions at various points - since you need to know those your self.  But I'll try deducing things from the code.

`x_train` is a 2d array with shape (m,n):

```
m = len(x_train)               # x_train.shape[0]
n = len(x_train[0])            # x_train.shape[1]
weights = np.zeros((m,1))      # (m,1)
b = 0
for i in range(iterations):
    loss = []
    z = np.dot(x_train.T,weights) + b  # dot (n,m) with (m,1) => (n,1)
    A = 1/(1+np.exp(-z))               # (n,1)
    cost = (-1/m)*np.sum(y_train*np.log(A)+(1-y_train)*np.log(1-A))
                      
    # y_train - unknown shape, could it be (m,)?
    # that would explain A-y_train shape of (n,m)
    dw = (1/m)*np.dot((A-y_train),x_train.T)   # dot (n,m), (n,m)
```

Comment: Thank s adding `y_train = y_train.reshape(n,1)` solved my problem